# Using a for loop inside a ssh statement replaces variable with empty string

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop, ssh

I have the following statement in a bash script:

```sh
ssh $host "cd /directory; for i in *$date.gz; do echo $i; done; exit"
```

I expect it to print the name of each file in the directory that ends with the date, and is a zip file. By ssh-ing to the host on the command line, and searching the directory, I find that there should be 5 such files. However, this script returns 5 blank lines. I checked if the `$date` variable was properly defined inside the quotes (it was). When I replaced `$i` with `'adf'`, the script printed

```sh
adf
adf
adf
adf
adf
```

So it is correctly filtering out those 5 files, but it is just not printing their names, and is replacing the `$i` in the statement with nothing (so that that line is just `echo`). Why is it doing this, and how can I make it print the filenames? The same thing happens when I run this line on the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By double-quoting your command, the variable expansion occurs *before* the `ssh` call.

So when you call this command line:

```sh
ssh $host "cd /directory; for i in *$date.gz; do echo $i; done; exit"
```

It calls the `ssh` command with two arguments: `$host` and `"cd /directory; for i in *$date.gz; do echo $i; done; exit"`

The second argument picks the content of the `date` variable and the `i` variable when the string is built. But at this time, you do NOT have the correct value for `i` yet.

I think that escaping `$i` into `\$i` should solve your issue:

```sh
ssh $host "cd /directory; for i in *$date.gz; do echo \$i; done; exit"
```